# How does SpringBoot integrate activiti automatically create database tables?

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I am learning Spring Boot and attempting to integrate it with Activiti. However, I am having problems automatically creating the database tables. I am using Spring Boot 3.1.0 and have included Activiti and MySQL dependencies in my `pom.xml` file. Here is a snippet of my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<!-- Activiti -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0.M4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti.dependencies</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0.M4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<!-- MySQL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also included the following configuration in my `application.yml` file:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  activiti:
    database-schema-update: true
```

What could be the issue preventing the automatic creation of my Activiti database tables?